# Why the same statement with long device name cannot query data when can successfully insert data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Why the same statement with long device name cannot query data when can successfully insert data in Apache IoTDB?
I am now using stand-alone Version 0.13.3 of Apache IoTDB, and tried to query data of special device name: "select last js_data from root.DATA_UYQUONCG_1.`2.0.0.0.29.222.3641704448` ". With adding backquotes, the query result remains empty when having data. This statement can write data into IoTDB, but cannot query data out. Anyone know what may be the problem?